# Slow Performance of Levenshtein distance formula in big database

Tags: mysql, levenshtein-distance

I used this query for searching company details

```
select * 
from company_details 
where levenshtein_ratio('New York Life Insurance Company',`cmp_name`) > 50
```

company_details table has more than 1 million records

But it is too slow it gets records after 1 or 2 minutes some time.

My Levenshtein function is:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
        DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
      RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s2_len;
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
      END WHILE;
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
          SET c = c + 1;
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
          END IF;
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
            IF c > c_temp THEN 
              SET c = c_temp; 
            END IF;
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
END
```

and ratio function:

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL in general is not optimized for partial string searches, although some databases do have functionality to help (Postgres has indexes based on n-grams, for instance).

For your purpose, you might start with a full-text index and make sure that the company name has some full words that are correct:  "New York", "Life", "Insurance" or "Company".  This will then reduce the space for the Levenshtein distance calculation.

You might also search around on the web for a more efficient implementation (I can't really judge if yours is more or less efficient).

Comment: This is a proper answer, not a comment :)